# Using AngularJS with a factory and a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to do the following:

When a user accesses "`localhost/people/:id`", the information about the respective person is taken from a MongoDB and displayed via Angular.

I have my api, which works perfectly fine, I've double-checked.

I'm using the latest AngularJS (1.4.9) and the new Router (angular-new-router or ngNewRouter).

I have an Angular module:

```
var personModule = angular.module('app.personDetailed', []);
```

a factory:

```
personModule.factory('personService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    get : function(id) {
      return $http.get('/api/people/' + id);
    }  
  }  
}]);
```

and a controller:

```
personModule.controller('PersonDetailedController', ['$routeParams', '$scope', 'personService', PersonDetailedController]);

function PersonDetailedController($routeParams, $scope, personService) {

  var id = $routeParams.id;

  personService.get(id).then(function(res) {   
    $scope.item = res.data;  
  });
}
```

This all should be displayed in this view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="PersonDetailedController">
  <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
</div>
```

*(yes, I'm not bothering trying to parse json yet).*

**The problem is, I am unable to use both `$scope` and `$routeParams` at the same time. I can only have one or the other.** If I use both, the `$scope` works fine, but the `$routeParams` is empty.

Here's the main controller, just in case:

```
var appModule = angular.module('app', ['app.main', 'app.personDetailed', 'ngNewRouter', 'ngResource']);

appModule.controller('AppController', ['$router', AppController]);

function AppController($router) {     
  $router.config([
   { path: '/', component: 'main'}
   { path: '/people/:id', component: 'personDetailed'}
  ]);
}
```

Comment: The doco seems to indicate you should use the *"controller as"* format (ie, no `$scope`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the new router does away with `$scope` and binds to the controller instance in the template instead.

Looks like you should use `this` instead

```
personModule.controller('PersonDetailedController', ['$routeParams', 'personService', PersonDetailedController]);

function PersonDetailedController($routeParams, personService) {
    var personDetailed = this,
        id = $routeParams.id;

    personService.get(id).then(function(res) {   
        personDetailed.item = res.data;  
    });
}
```

and your view (do not use `ng-controller`)

```
<h2>{{ personDetailed.item }}</h2>
```